# Unable to set Form field value by default in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and trying to set the default value of form field using form name. I don't know what wrong when I type in input field then I'm able to see the value in below heading. But, default value is not set by javascript code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="testForm">
<input ng-model="testForm.name">

<h1>My name is {{testForm.name}}</h1>
</form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testForm = {};
    $scope.testForm.name = "John Doe";
});
</script>

<p>When you change the name in the input field, the changes will affect the model, and it will also affect the name property in the controller.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
          var vm = this;
          vm.testForm = {};
          vm.testForm.name = "John Doe";
        }])
```

HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <form name="testForm">
  <input ng-model="vm.testForm.name">
  <h1>My name is {{vm.testForm.name}}</h1>
  </form>
</div>
```

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/nRkZ6KgMlubnhYxh3hEf?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But why do we need to do like this.... I mean why it didn't work directly in $scope.

Comment: read this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-value="defaulVar" or value="default" to set a default.

```
<input ng-model="testForm.name" ng-value="testForm.name" value="default">
```

Best
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Changing testForm.name to simply name makes the trick:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="testForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <h1>My name is {{ name }}</h1>
  </form>
</div>

<p>When you change the name in the input field, the changes will affect the model, and it will also affect the name property in the controller.</p>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
  });
</script>
```

I don't have idea why ..so if someone can tell me why i'll be very grateful :-)

Comment: What if I have two forms with same field name and inside same controller. Will this work?